# Delete all directories and its files older than a 60 days regardless of whether the directory is empty or not

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ubuntu

I'm trying to delete all directories in `/mnt/games/codes` that are older than **60** days.  The directories could be empty or not, but I want them all deleted.

So looking on here, I found this command:

```
find /mnt/games/codes/* -mtime +60 -type d -exec rm -rf {} \;
```

But it gives me this error:

> No such file or directory

So then I tried this:

```
find /mnt/games/codes/* -mtime +60 -type d -exec rmdir {} \;
```

But it's giving me a brand new error that looks like this:

> Directory not empty

Is there a way to delete these with one command?

Thanks!

Comment: What pathname was reported as being "no such file or directory"?  Does that pathname in fact exist?  It may help in debugging if you replace the `rm` command with `echo` so you can see what paths `find` is actually trying to operate on.  Of course, many of them may already have been deleted - it would have been smart to try with `echo` *before* using `rm`, in case the command was going to delete stuff you wanted to keep.

Comment: @NateEldredge It's odd, they all point to nonexistent folders. For example, here's one: the path is: `/mnt/games/codes/` and the error says: `find '/mnt/games/codes/game1_war' : No such file or directory`.  But that's odd because the path exists, but the `game1_war` does not.  So I am not sure where the `find` command is getting these non-existent names.

Comment: Are you sure you want to delete directories even if the files in those directories have been recently updated?

Comment: @TedLyngmo Yes I'm sorry, that is correct, its the folder create date that is important in this case.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your issue is because `find` is deleting its search base directories before it has finished iterating these, so calling your `rm -rf` on already deleted entries.

This is easily fixed by adding the `-depth` option.

Also, **you should really end the `rm` options with a double dash `--`**, to prevent having arguments provided by the `find` command, to be interpreted as options arguments by the `rm` command.

```sh
find /mnt/games/codes/ -depth -mtime '+60' -type d -exec rm -rf -- {} \;
```

Comment: `--` is not needed in this case because {} will be replace by /mnt/games/codes/<something> and it will not be interpreted as options.

Comment: Well If you think a fire alarm is not needed because there is no legitimate fire here … Up to you.

Comment: I am just saying that *in this case* `--` is not needed because even when you have a directory named `-d` underneath /mnt/games/codes/, `{}` will be replaced by `/mnt/games/codes/-d`, or you can provide an example it is needed in this case when you find from an absolute directory?

Comment: I do not pretend it is needed for your specific case right-now. I just enforce to promote safe or good practices (even if not needed here) because there are various users here, some are beginners who (should not) just copy-paste code they do not fully understand.

Answer (score 1):

The following works because it finds, and then pipe to xargs. I believe it will prevent the "arg list too long" problem as well when you have a lot to find.

```
find /mnt/games/codes/* -mtime -60 -type d | xargs rm -rf
```